# Handling Concurrent Modification Exception android

Tags: android, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I want to avoid concurrent modification exception. So trying to make a copy of hash map. Even then it throws concurrent modification while removing element from original map. Below is the code to make copy, Is there any mistake?

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> makeCopy(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> origMap) {

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> copy=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    Iterator<String> iterator = origMap.keySet().iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        copy.put(key,  new ArrayList<String>(origMap.get(key)));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Or Is there any possibilities to handle it after catching it in try catch block ?

Purpose of creating new copy:
Actually 1 copy of Hashmap values should be sent to another activity(b) which has thread operations, while original copy will be modified in the activity(A) which calls the other activity(b), thats why trying to create a copy of hash map with different reference.

Comment: try `private synchronized HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> makeCopy`

Answer (score 0):

Use ConcurrentHashmap instead of Hashmap or get a synchronized map for reading values https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html .

Answer (score 0):

As axierjhtjz has put, the right way is to let only iterator modify the collection.

Alternatively use a ConcurrentHashMap.

Some Benefits: -->

> You should use ConcurrentHashMap when you need very high concurrency in your project.
>       It is thread safe without synchronizing the whole map.
>       Reads can happen very fast while write is done with a lock.
>       There is no locking at the object level.
>       The locking is at a much finer granularity at a hashmap bucket level.
>       ConcurrentHashMap doesn’t throw a ConcurrentModificationException if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it.
>       ConcurrentHashMap uses multitude of locks.

Second last point is what can help you :

> ConcurrentHashMap doesn’t throw a ConcurrentModificationException if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it.

Read in detail [here](http://crunchify.com/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronizedmap-how-a-hashmap-can-be-synchronized-in-java/).

Answer (score 0):

A **Collection** cannot be modified(add/removing) at the same time when it is iterated. You can only use *iterator.remove()* to remove an item. Otherwise it will throw **ConcurrentModificationException**.

One simple solution would be that you can use a simple for loop(don't use Enhanced for loop) instead of iterator.